# How can I protect my API and know what is calling it?

Tags: api, security, oauth, restful-authentication

I am building a Web application, and Web API. The Web application will do ajax call to the server and receive JSON results. The same will happen to the Web API.

I am planing to ask developers to use keys to access the Web API so that I can charge for their uses of it.

The problem is the Web API will be use by the Web application to get the content for the web pages. Is there a way to know if it is my Web application using the Web API or someone trying to highjack the API so that they don't have to pay for it?

I am using PHP on my server.

Comment: The web application should have an api key, too.

Comment: It's the user side with JavaScript that will be calling the API... A user could seal that key. No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to secure something on the web, it might be useful to think about how you want to protect the information that you provide by the api before you try to find a technique for protecting the api.

An example:

Say that your api provides the current weather in London and your web application is an open web page that provides this information while also showing some web ads. You don't want someone else to use the api and show the Lonodn weather somewhere else without showing the web ad because that would ruin your sole income from this service.

You could limit access to the api by providing i.e. short time keys or another complicated protocol, but the problem here is that the information you provides, the London weather, is available to anyone on the web page anyway. If someone wants to "steal" your information and provide the London weather on a different web site they can just write a script that loads your web application, reads the information from the web page and display this in their own web application.

If a person is able to access the information, then he can also write a script that reads this information and display the information somewhere else.

Securing information is actually more about limiting *who* you want to give access and not so much about *how* they should get access. If you or your clients makes this information freely available on the net in one form or another, then you cannot (technically) prevent someone else from picking it up and redistribute it.

Comment: It is more about bandwidth. I don't want someone just plugin in my API and getting a free ride. I want them to be able to access the API but with a fee. They can take the data and redistribute it I don't care. Since the data changes often...

Comment: You do provide the data in your own web application. Do you charge users for using the web application? Do they have to log in to use it?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to protect completely but there are techniques that help. ApiAxle (disclaimer: my company) gives you the option of using [short lived keys](http://apiaxle.com/docs/signing-requests/). These will be impossible for a leecher to generate without knowing your secret key. Paired with rate limiting you're getting somewhat closer to where you want to be.

Not foolproof but a start.

Comment: But could I use something like this? http://www.swollenpickles.com/2008/01/16/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-and-bandwidth-theft/